# Strange controller test behavior if cancan is enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, cancan

I have an application with devise/cancan and a typical restful products controller with the following action:

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
end
```

In the `products_controller_spec.rb` I am testing it like this:

```
describe "GET 'new'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    Product.should_receive(:new)
    get 'new'
  end
end
```

If I run the test without cancan it works as expected and passes. If I add the cancan `load_and_authorize_resource` I am getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Product.should_receive(:new)
   (<Product(id: integer, tenant_id: integer, product_category_id: integer, tax_category_id: integer, brand_id: integer, name: string, description: string, order_quantity: decimal, size: decimal, decimal: decimal, items_per_unit: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) (class)>).new(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 2 times
```

I have to bypass it by adding `at_least(:one)` in the end (so it looks like `Product.should_receive(:new).at_least(:once)` and it passes again).

Why is this happening? It has to do with cancan right? Why cancan is calling it twice and is there a better way to test it?

I am getting all kind of errors in controller tests when I am adding cancan and I've started wondering what cancan is doing and I have this strange behavior.

I have tested the abilities of a user and I have wrote many integration tests without a problem.

**Last thing**: I have a before block on top of the tests that I am signing in and giving the right role/permissions for accessing the controller like the following:

```
  let!(:tenant) { create(:tenant) }
  let!(:role)   { Role.where(name: "Admin", tenant_id: tenant.id).first }
  let!(:user)   { create(:user, role: role, tenant: tenant) }

  before do
    Tenant.current_id = tenant.id
    user.confirm!
    sign_in(user)
  end
```

Is there a way to bypass cancan (like calling `skip_authorize_resource` in some way in the test) because I want to test the controller method itself, not the abilities and the roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `load` method of cancan, it does it for you automatically.

Change your action to:

```
def new
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Is load_and_authorize_resource provides something more in terms of security from authorize_resource or it just loads the resource?

Comment: you'd need load_and_authorize if you check properties on the objects. Personnaly I like cancan approach, it removes useless/obvious lines